# Different rotation combinations. First rotate around X-Axis then Z and then vice versa with same results.

Tags: geometry, rotations

First of all sorry, i am no mathematician and this might be a silly question, but i have the following problem.

I have a Program which rotates a 3D-Object first around the x-Axis **or** the Y-Axis and **then** around the z-Axis.
The rotations happen via given Axis and Rotationangle in degree.

An other Program now tries to recreate the Object **after** the rotaions with loading the original Object and rotating it. But it rotates always **first** around the z-Axis **then** the y-Axis and **then** the x-Axis.
Again the Rotations are simply defined by the Axis (z,y,x) and the Rotationangle like zRotation 90 = Rotation 90 degree around the z-Axis.

Is there a way to define the needed zRotation, yRotation and xRotation for the second program given the xRotation, yRotation and zRotation from the first Operation?

I tried to simply exchange the rotations which obviously did not work, because then the Object was rotated around the wrong axis.

Any help would be apreciated!

Edit:
trueCounter is used to check wheter i have only 1 rotation (so no change is necessary)
the xRotation, yRotation and zRotation are the Values for the other Program (whitch always starts with the z-Rotation) and the descr.Rotations are the ones the first Program used.

```
if (trueCounter > 1)
            {
                if (descr.Rotation_Z == 90)
                {
                    xRotation = (descr.Rotation_Y + 180) % 360;
                    yRotation = descr.Rotation_X;
                }
                else if (descr.Rotation_Z == 180)
                {
                    if (xRotation > 0 && xRotation != 180)
                        xRotation = (descr.Rotation_X + 180) % 360;
                    if (yRotation > 0 && yRotation != 180)
                        yRotation = (descr.Rotation_Y + 180) % 360;
                }
                else if (descr.Rotation_Z == 270)
                {
                    xRotation = descr.Rotation_Y;
                    yRotation = (descr.Rotation_X + 180) % 360;
                }
            }
```

This seems to work fine for the cases i tested so far, but i am not sure if it will work in all cases. 
Maybe someone who has a better understanding of it could give me a feedback.

Comment: Are the axes fixed in space? Or they are attached to an object?

Comment: @VasilyMitch I think they are fixed in space. But i am not 100% sure.

Comment: If you need to do it occasionally for limited number of angles, then try this https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/ If you need to come up with formula, it's quite complicated. Let me know if you need one

Comment: @VasilyMitch Thank you very much for that tool. It defenitly helps to get a better understanding and to debug my Program! And the Conversion to other Formats might be useful for other projects! And its just for the basic Rotations 90/180/270 degree.